# How to use Requisitions?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I am a relatively new halo 5 player, and I was wondering how to use the requisitions (the cards you obtain in packs). I have quite a few cards for different guns and vehicles, but I can't seem to figure out what they're used for.

I've figured out how to open packs here:

[image: halo 5 requisitions pack page]

But I can't figure out how to use this page at all:

[image: halo 5 customization page]

How can I use that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requisitions are primarily used in Warzone, but some also have an effect on Arena games:

- The customization tab of the start menu allows you to set armor type, visors, and weapon skins, which are unlocked with Requisitions. These change how you and your weapons look in Arena and Warzone.
- Any loadout weapons that you unlock become available to spawn with as many times as you want in Warzone games.
- Any power weapon and vehicle cards that you get each allow you to spawn a single one of those weapons or vehicles in a Warzone game.
- You can apply a single boost card to each game that you play by pressing A in the game lobby. They are specific to Arena or Warzone, and increase either XP or Req points gained for that game.